# Cannot Launch in AVD in the Emulator

Tags: android, cpu, android-studio

[image: This is the error]

Hello guys I have a problem about Android Studio. Whenever I want to open Emulator, It doesn't work and says (or you can click the picture):

```
Emulator: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.sse4a [bit 6]
```

I couldn't solve this problem. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed SDK and of course Android Studio. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same problem. This warning isn't a reason for emulator not working. Check virtualization support in your system as described in https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation

Comment: Nice answer, I'd think this question/answer pair would be more popular. One suggestion if you have time, per the SO guidelines (last time I checked) you could copy relevant snippets from the linked docs in the (unlikely here) case that the links go stale.